# TeamCity Build Web Solution with Multiple Projects ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, teamcity

I have what I believe is a really common scenario with an ASP.NET MVC 3 solution. It has a WEB project and a DAL class library. I have the all my data access in the class library, which is required to be built before the web project.

When I rebuild my solution in standard Visual Studio I have no issues. But lets say I make a data change (for example to the database) and check in the DBML (LINQ to SQL) file and the corresponding reference files from the WEB Project.

What I'm seeing is TeamCity not cleaning/rebuilding the class library DLL at all. Below is my solution configuration. How can I force TeamCity to rebuild each project as it doesn't seem to be doing such. I have to actually check in the bin/debug DLL locally in order for TeamCity to successfully build. I feel that should not be the case. Do I need to setup a build step for each project...?

[image]

Comment: You have `Copy Local` set to True? What Platform do you have setup for the Debug solution configuration in Visual Studio? Any CPU or x86 or x64 or all? Make sure Build is checked for each project and then set the Platform in TeamCity. Also, why using Debug, these artifacts for production or qa?

Comment: @aherrick do you need any more help with this?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I force TeamCity to rebuild each project as it doesn't seem to be doing such.

I think the surest way to do this is to enforce a clean checkout of the source tree prior to each build. (see also: nuke it from orbit.)

You can have TeamCity do this for you by enabling the `Clean all files before build` option on *Version Control Settings* -> *Checkout Settings*.  This option deletes the entire checkout directory and does a full, clean checkout of all the sources prior to the build.  The [TeamCity 'Clean Checkout'](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Clean+Checkout) documentation has more info.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your build configuration (in Visual Studio) is messed up.

First off, make sure your DAL reference is a project reference, not a file reference.

The easiest way to correct this is to remove the reference and re-add it. While adding, ensure you are looking at the projects tab. This should reset the project dependencies.

To ensure that the MVC project depends on the DAL project, right-click on the MVC project and select *Project Dependencies...* from the context menu. The DAL project should be checked.

Comment: I seeing this error though looks like its during my deploy step..  CSC error CS0006: Metadata file '\\server\temptest\bin\TempTestSite.dll' could not be found Project TempTestSite.WEB.WEB\TempTestSite.WEB.csproj failed. Project

Comment: Strange...Is the bin directory getting cleaned out before your deploy step?